# preg_match to select match in first selector

Tags: php, regex

I have this string to test and can't manage to make it works as I want :

```
<?php
$string = '500 or fatal error ?';
$regex = '#(fatal|500)#';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $return)) {
    // Return 500
    echo $return[1];
}
?>
```

I want my script to return fatal instead of 500 because it's my first selector.
Is it possible ?

Thanks by advance, and sorry for my poor english.

P.S. : Maybe my title isn't really clear, but I don't know how to explain it better. If you find it, change it.

Comment: I don't know if regexes are the right tool here, as they will read strings from left to right.

Comment: well, first match was `500`, matching starts from the begining of the string, order in your regex here makes no difference

Comment: @MarkoD Is it possible to change this behavior ?

Comment: If you prefer a textual message over a numerical one, you probably need to regexes: The first to check for the text and if not found a second to check for a number. Or you just check for the number and have the numbers map to a text via for example an array.

Comment: @RocketHazmat : This example is really simplier as in reality (I have more than 150 selectors). if possible, I prefer to keep the regex system.

Comment: @jeroen It's not number against texts. This is simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with only one regex, you can do it like this:

```
$selectors = array( 'fatal', '500'); // Array of selectors (in priority order)

$delimiter = '/';
$regex = $delimiter . '(' . implode('|', array_map( 'preg_quote', $selectors, array_fill( 0, count( $selectors), '/'))) . ')' . $delimiter;
preg_match_all( $regex, $string, $matches);
```

See which of the selectors we found, in order of the array:

```
$found_selectors = array_flip( $matches[1]);
foreach( $selectors as $selector) { 
    if( isset( $found_selectors[$selector])) 
        return $selector;
}
```

Note that I flipped the `$matches[1]` array to get constant lookup time into the array, instead of doing an `array_search()` / `in_array()` which will both do a linear search.

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/nrOkef) that this produces `fatal`, given your input string.

Comment: Woah ! It seems to work exactly as I want. I'm looking on it to see how it works, thanks a lot !

Comment: I sort of glanced over the explanation, but `$regex` is just forming a dynamic regex just like you had, except I use an array of `$selectors` and make sure to properly escape all of the selectors with `preg_quote()`. Then, you get back an array in `$matches[1]` just like you did previously, I just flip the array, and iterate over the `$selectors` (which are in priority order) to see which one (if any) were found in the string. The first one that gets found, gets returned.

Comment: That's what I see. Just take some time to understand everything. Perfect logic, thanks !

Comment: Why not just do 
`implode($selectors)` 
instead of 
`implode('|', array_map( 'preg_quote', $selectors, array_fill( 0, count( $selectors), '/')))` ?

Comment: If your selectors have a `/` in it, you'll form an invalid regex. That's why the array gets mapped with `preg_quote()`, to turn any `/` into `\/`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of regular expression engines: `text-directed engines`, and `regex-directed` engines.

php is `regex-directed` engine which would always return the leftmost match, even if "500" match could be found later

> The engine will start at the first character of the string. It will
>   try all possible permutations of the regular expression at the first
>   character. Only if all possibilities have been tried and found to
>   fail, will the engine continue with the second character in the text.
>   Again, it will try all possible permutations of the regex, in exactly
>   the same order. The result is that the regex-directed engine will
>   return the leftmost match.

You can find more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I assume it's not possible to force php behaving as a text-directed engine ?

Comment: @Tyrius no you can't force it to  text-directed engine

Answer (score 2):

it's not possible as you are envisioning, but a different implementation will make it work

```
$string = '500 or fatal error';
$regexes = array('#\bfatal\b#', '#\b500\b#');

$match = null;
foreach ($regexes as $re)
  if (preg_match($re, $string, $match))
    break;
# $match is null -> not found
```

Comment: This also requires `n` regexes and `n` evaluations for `n` selectors, where the OP has 150 this may get expensive.

Comment: I know it, but for my own reasons I wanted to do a regex search. 
It seems to be unpossible, so I will return back to this way.